# Split datafram from one column to two column by odd/even row,

Tags: python, pandas, extract, feature-extraction

Hi I've a dataframe with one colone

```
| id|text                                              | 
|---|-------------------------------------------------:|
| 0 |[(BFM Bourse) - Même si cela ne possède aucun ... |
| 1 |[Négatif]\n                                       |
| 2 |[(BFM Bourse) - Pour la dernière séance (tronq... |
| 3 |[Neutre]\n                                        |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I'd like to text row with large text to column `text` and rows with `Négatif` or `Positif` or `Neutre`  to columns `sentiment`.

My idea is to retrieve one by one and concate them.
I've retrieved `text` by doign this.

```
text = pd.DataFrame(data.loc[::2,], columns=['text'])
```

I every text rows is folllowed by `sentiment` word I slid using step 2.
Here I got text but how to get `Sentiment`?

Comment: Yes i'm sure for that.

Comment: Thanks this was what I'm looking, could delete post as duplicated? But the kind he asked question make it difficult to find, event stack did not suggest.
THANKSSSSSS

Comment: True I agree, couldnt find it either, great spot by @MattR.